# Codepoint not legal - SVCCODEPOINT

Tags: xquery, marklogic

What does the below error mean in xquery :-

```
SVC-CODEPOINT: (err:FOCH0001) xdmp:unquote("{ "info": { "title": "Inventory...") -- Codepoint not legal
```

Getting the above error while running xquery file where I have defined a mapping file inside a variable like -

```
let $mapping := xdmp:unquote('{
    "info": {
        "title": "Inventory"
    },
    "InvTable": [
        {
            "prefix": "pdw",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
    "ViewNames": {
        "InvTable": {
            "$ref": "pdw/DAU"
        }
    }
}')
```

Comment: You may have odd characters hidden in your text, like unusual whitespace, or control characters that are not shown in your editor. Make sure your unquote value is clean.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically saying you have an invalid character. A codepoint is the underlying numerical value for a character and there's something in your string that isn't legal to become JSON, probably. I suggest you simplify what you're unquoting until you find where that's coming from.

Comment: I have updated it in the question can you please check ?